# How to write a program to download bunch of images from url and upload it to AWS S3 Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can someone please help me to write a program to download image files from url and upload same file to AWS S3 and delete the downloaded image.

```
var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};

download('https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png', 'google.png', function(){
  console.log('done');
  fs.readFile('google.png', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("Read file failed: "+ err)
          }
 let params = {
     Bucket: waftBucket,
     Key: 'google.png',
     Body: data,
     ContentType: 'image/png',
     ACL: 'public-read'
 };
let s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
 s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
     return console.log('There was an error uploading image: ' + err.message);
   }
   console.log('Successfully Uploaded.');
fs.unlink(google.png);
 });

    });  
});
```

**The above code is working for 1 File, but it's not working for loops**

```
    var download = function(uri, filename, callback){
  request.head(uri, function(err, res, body){
    console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
    console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
    request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
  });
};


var getFileName = function(url){
    return url.split("/")[5];
}

var data = {
frags : [
    {url: "https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.39678.jpg", fileName: getFileName("https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.39678.jpg")},
    {url: "https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.4506.jpg", fileName: getFileName("https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.4506.jpg")},
    {url: "https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.29601.jpg", fileName: getFileName("https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.29601.jpg")},
    {url: "https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.32597.jpg", fileName: getFileName("https://fimgs.net/images/perfume/375x500.32597.jpg")}
]};
for(var i=0; i<data.frags.length; i++){
download(data.frags[i].url, data.frags[i].fileName, function(){
  fs.readFile(data.frags[i].fileName, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log("Read file failed: "+ err)
          }
 let params = {
     Bucket: waftBucket,
     Key: 'images/'+data.frags[i].fileName,
     Body: data,
     ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
     ACL: 'public-read'
 };
let s3 = new AWS.S3(); 
 s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) {
     return console.log('There was an error uploading image: ' + err.message);
   }
   console.log('Successfully Uploaded.');
   fs.unlink(data.frags[i].fileName);
 });

    });  
});
}
```

Is there any other way to do this? Is it possible to read the contents of URL and save it directly to AWS S3 bucket without downloading and deleting the file in temp folder?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing much about the exact use case, I would recommend checking out the AWS CLI to do this. It provides a [sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) option which is described as below:

> Syncs directories and S3 prefixes. Recursively copies new and updated
>   files from the source directory to the destination. Only creates
>   folders in the destination if they contain one or more files.

So, you need to download your files to one temp folder, sync it with S3 using the CLI and then delete the folder (using rimraf or fs).

Answer (score 0):

`s3.putObject` only supports single object upload per HTTP request.

> As all functions are `async` using for loop will create a lot of mess.

So, either you can use promises to make multiple requests one after another or use a better solution as pointed out by @kmukkamala.

Install S3 tools on the server and run the following command to sync the entire directory.

```
s3cmd sync myserverDir s3://bucket/
```

You can schedule a corntab to run the script every 10-20 mins and then delete the folder or files.

Comment: Side-note: These days, it is recommended to use the official [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) rather than `s3cmd`.